# how to fix "MetaMask - RPC Error: The method 'eth_signTransaction' does not exist / is not available"?

Tags: web3js, transactions, metamask

I am learning how to use Web3.js and I am getting this error:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: The method 'eth_signTransaction' does not exist / is not available.
```

When trying to sign a transaction (for later using sendSignedTransacetion).

This is the code:

```
web3.eth.signTransaction({
  from: "addressxxx",
  gasPrice: "20000000000",
  gas: "21000",
  to: 'addressyyy',
  value: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether'),
  data: ""
}).then(console.log);
```

My purpose is to try to get the signed transaction data in HEX format to pass it later to the sendSignedTransaction.

What could it be the problem?

Comment: Currently it is not supported by Metamask: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3475.